# Get text box value in alert function

Tags: sharepoint-online

i am trying to get the text box value in alert function but can't be get the value but show the empty alert. My code as below:`<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>
    <meta name="WebPartPageExpansion" content="full" />
    <!-- Add your CSS styles to the following file -->
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Content/App.css" />
    <!-- Add your JavaScript to the following file -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/App.js"></script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
 <div>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
               function show(){
                alert(‘test:’ + $('#txtPrice').val());
                }
    </script>
 <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" >
  <tr>
     <td width="20%">
      <label id="Label1" runat="server" >Today price:</label> 
         <input id="txtPrice" type="text" />&nbsp;
     </td>

  </tr>

 </table>
      <div>
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="show();" id="btnCreate" style="background-color: #4CAF50; border: none; color: white; padding: 7px 15px; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; display: inline-block; font-size: 14px; margin: 4px 2px; cursor: pointer;" /> 
           </td>
        </tr>
       </table>
   </div> 
 </div>
</asp:Content>`

Comment: I see the function show(), but I don't see where it is ever called.

Comment: Also, if this is a true copy and pasted of the code, you have invalid quotes on the alert.     alert(‘test:’    vs.   alert('test:'

Comment: i was changed the called funtion show() in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the solution `$("input[id='txtFirstName']").val()`